# Highcharts query

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, highcharts

I want to use the highcharts library but it doesn't work. I've checked it in JSFiddle it is working fine but it is not working in my browser.

What is the problem? please tell me.

Here is the code:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Speedometer'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        center: ['50%', '100%'],
        background: [{
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#FFF'],
                    [1, '#333']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '109%'
            }, {
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#333'],
                    [1, '#FFF']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 1,
            outerRadius: '107%'
        }, {
            // default background
        }, {
            backgroundColor: '#DDD',
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '105%',
            innerRadius: '103%'
        }]
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200,

        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        minorTickWidth: 1,
        minorTickLength: 10,
        minorTickPosition: 'inside',
        minorTickColor: '#666',

        tickPixelInterval: 30,
        tickWidth: 2,
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickLength: 10,
        tickColor: '#666',
        labels: {
            step: 2,
            rotation: 'auto'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'km/h'
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 120,
            color: '#55BF3B' // green
        }, {
            from: 120,
            to: 160,
            color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
        }, {
            from: 160,
            to: 200,
            color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]        
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]

}, 
// Add some life
function (chart) {
    if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
        setInterval(function () {
            var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                newVal,
                inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

            newVal = point.y + inc;
            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
                newVal = point.y - inc;
            }

            point.update(newVal);

        }, 3000);
    }
});
    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
     <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
```

I  also want to  get the data from MYSQL database using AJAX which shows the current speed. I have written the query but I don't know how to use in this code.

Please tell me the method, I am new so I don't know how to use Highcharts

Here is my PHP code:

```
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT speed FROM gps WHERE DeviceId=25 ORDER BY TIME DESC LIMIT 1")
or die(mysql_error()); 
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
array('label' => 'Speed', 'type' => 'number')
);
$rows = array();
while ($nt = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{               
$temp = array();

$temp[] = array('v' => $nt['speed']);

$rows[]['c'] = $temp;

}
$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

please tell me how can I use this in above HighChart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you failed to load jQuery on which your code depends on. Adding this code before loading highcharts should do the trick.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also you can't purely use JavaScript to fetch data from a database. You will have to use a server scripting language such as PHP, Ruby, Python, ASP.Net e.t.c. JavaScript is client side only.

Comment: Thanks now my chart is appearing. I am using PHP to get the data from MYSQL but i don't know how to call the JSon table in this code. can you tell me the method please

Comment: @Sandy Since you're already using jQuery, `jQuery.getJSON()` should do the trick. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget to include jQuery?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```